# Can you create a cycle in the directory structure using symbolic link?

Tags: filesystems, symlink

Operating System Concepts says

> when we add links, the tree structure is destroyed, resulting in a
>   simple graph structure (Figure 11.13).
>
> [image]

Could you create the cycle book->avi->book using symbolic links?

Should `/avi/text` and `/avi/mail` also appear under `/avi/book/`? Should `/avi/book/count` also appear under `/avi/`? If both answers are no, can you make them happen?

If you have some problem understanding the figure just like I do, here is my guess: The root of the tree is a directory named "root" which contains three directory entries for subdirectory "avi", regular file "tc" and subdirectory "jim" respectively. Similar explanation for other parts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Symlinks can easily create loops.  The simplest is to have a symlink point to the current directory.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ln -s . XXX
$ cd XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX
$ pwd
/tmp/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX
```

But we can also do it with book and avi as in your diagram by making there be a book symlink inside the avi directory

eg

```
$ mkdir /tmp/XXXX
$ cd /tmp/XXXX
$ mkdir book book/avi
$ cd book/avi
$ pwd
/tmp/XXXX/book/avi
$ ln -s .. book
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sweh sweh 2 Sep 28 22:53 book -> ../
$ cd book/avi/book/avi/book/avi
$ pwd
/tmp/XXXX/book/avi/book/avi/book/avi/book/avi
```

Comment: Thanks. In the figure,  why do not all of the files "text" "mail" and "count" appear under both the directory and the symbolic link to it? Can you make that happen?

Comment: The grey "avi" is a different node to the blue "avi" in that diagram.  Just because the name is the same doesn't mean they are the same thing.  The whole path is important.  Otherwise `/bin` and `/opt/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` would be the same, and they're not.

Comment: Thanks. Should `/avi/text` and `/avi/mail` also appear under `/avi/book/`? Should `/avi/book/count` also appear under `/avi/`? If both answers are no, can you make them happen?

Comment: In the graph you presented, the answer is "no".  But with symlinks you can make any node of the graph link to any other node, so you can build a complete spider's web of connections if you were so inclined ;-)

Comment: Between "book" and "avi", one is symlink to another. How can some files under "book"  not appear under "avi", and vice versa?

Comment: "book" and "avi" are different nodes.  Think of the symlink as creating the _link_ between nodes.  It's one of the lines, not the box.